# How to remove eslint error on redux action in props?

Tags: reactjs, redux, eslint

In my project, I am using Redux alongside with React. When using a redux action, I need to import it, and specify it in my component's props. As a result, eslint warns me that the method specified in my props has already been declared in the upper scope (Yes I know !). When I remove it from the props, then the action is just not called at all, and do not work as expected (nothing happens).

How can I make it work without any eslint warnings ? (No, I don't want to disable it ;))

Here's my component code:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Dimmer, Loader } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { authenticateAzure } from '../../actions/auth_actions';

// I have an eslint error on the props here
const Authenticate = ({ authenticateAzure }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    authenticateAzure(window.location.origin);
  });

  return (
    <div className="authorize-container">
      <Dimmer active>
        <Loader />
      </Dimmer>
    </div>
  );
};

Authenticate.propTypes = {
  authenticateAzure: PropTypes.func,
};

Authenticate.defaultProps = {
  authenticateAzure: () => {},
};

export default connect(null, { authenticateAzure })(Authenticate);
```

And here is the eslint error I mentioned:

```js
'authenticateAzure' is already declared in the upper scope. eslint(no-shadow)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have shadow here:

```
import { authenticateAzure } from '../../actions/auth_actions';

// authenticateAzure  shadows outer scope
const Authenticate = ({ authenticateAzure }) => {...}
```

You just need to rename any of them, for example

```
import { authenticateAzure: authAction } from '../../actions/auth_actions';

// authenticateAzure  shadows outer scope
const Authenticate = ({ authenticateAzure }) => {
  // use authAction()...
}
```

Comment: The props I'm using here refers to the action, that is not passed from a parent component; that's why they have the same name ! If I change the name of the imported action, like `import { authenticateAzure as authAction } from '../../actions/auth_actions';`, then the action won't work either... (nothing happens = action is not triggered) Same thing if I change my props' name :/